# Does Sass have a switch function?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

With Sass' ability to use variables, one would hope there is a large set of logic functions we can do with them.

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
$someVar: someValue !default;

@switch $someVar
{
    @case 'red':
        .arbitrary-css here {}

    @break;

    @case 'green':
        .arbitrary-css here {}

    @break;

    @case 'blue':
        .arbitrary-css here {}

    @break;
}
```

However, I can't find anything in the Sass reference about this.

Comment: Case is just an if/else in disguise.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sass doesn't support Switch Case.

Sass only support four control directives:

- @if
- @for
- @each
- @while

Comment: Github Issue: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/554 (closed)

Answer (score 61):

No there isn't any supported switch statement in sass but if you only need to use the switch statement to tweak a variable, you can use sass maps in a switch statement sort of way.

**Using SASS maps in place of a switch statement**

```
$newVar: map-get((
    case_1_test_name : case_1_return_value,
    case_2_test_name : case_2_return_value,
), $testVar);
```

So here's an example:

```
$vehicle: car;

$vehicleSeating: map-get((
    car : 4,
    bus : 20,
), $vehicle);

//$vehicleSeating = 4
```

The above example translated into if/else statements:

```
$vehicle: car;

@if ($vehicle == 'car') {
    $vehicleSeating: 4;
} @else if ($vehicle == 'bus'){
    $vehicleSeating: 20;
}

//$vehicleSeating = 4
```

Comment: I'm providing an alternative to using switch statements in SASS by using SASS maps in a way that a lot of people wouldn't think of. I've removed the unrelated bit of the answer about generating CSS from a SASS map.

Comment: So rather than the answer just being "it's not possible", the answer is "It's not possible, but you can try this instead"

Comment: Just providing an alternative that is far cleaner than a stack of if/else statements.

Comment: I think this is nifty technique. I'm even going to refactor some of mixins using sass maps for media queries. Thanks!

Comment: @Vladyn Try this mixin out for media queries. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mq-scss I think it's the most powerful media query mixin on the internet.

Comment: Thanks @DanielTonon, this looks interesting. Very similar to one I'm using across latest 2 projects also as a SASS mixin